# C# Lambda - Where - Mulitple expressions of the same criteria

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Hypothetical - A party store wants to select people based on criteria from their DB.

DB name "BirthDays" fields: Day, Month, Year

The "where" needs to be dynamic to take in each consideration for search instance:

1. Day = 12, Month = 1, Year = 1962
2. Day = 3, Month = 4, Year = 1977 ; Day = 13, Month = 4, Year = 1977
3. Day = 20, Month = 8, Year = 1941 ; Day = 9, Month = 1, Year = 1991 ; Day = 19, Month = 11, Year = 1986 ; Day = 25, Month = 2, Year = 1956

Below obviously will not work because it only considers one search instance when there may be 3 or even 10:

```
query.Where(o => o.Day == 3 && o.Month == 4 && o.Year == 1997);
```

I tried looking into Expression and ParameterExpression, but couldn't wrap my head around it.

[NOTE]
@Luaan is the closest one so far, adding "||" will not address #1.

Comment: Are you looking for a simple `||` (or) here? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: you can use three lists to store days,months & years & then use Contains() in where condition.I will post an answer for this if for you, my understanding is correct !

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify that

Comment: @JayMee -- Yes, because it is dynamic. It won't be the same every time. On one search it is #1 but another person searches an its #3.  Each user has a different search

Comment: @AnswerIsNot42, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq)'s a nice way to dynamically build Where clause.

Comment: @ieaglle - yeah I did that Google search too, I didn't understand it so I came here

Comment: i think i understand... you want search multiple things but store them in separate queries? for example search #1 store results in first element. then search #2 and store results in second element etc ?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - No, it's all the same search. Luaan is closest (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to build this dynamically, it's pretty easy with a couple of extension methods. For example:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>(this IQueryable<T> @this)
  => _ => false;

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>
  (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
  =>
  Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
  (
    Expression.OrElse
    (
      left, 
      Expression.Invoke
      (
        right, 
        left.Parameters.Cast<Expression>()
      )
    ), 
    left.Parameters
  );
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var predicate = query.False();

foreach (var date in filterDates)
{
  predicate = 
    predicate.Or(i => i.Day == date.Day && i.Month == date.Month && i.Year == date.Year);
}

query = query.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: The second part is BINGO, that's kinda what I'm looking for....the first part I don't understand :( ...that's what I'm trying to figure out :) [EDITED - spelling]

Comment: @AnswerIsNot42 What part is giving you trouble? The first function simply returns a typed `false` expression - important for easy of typing, basically. The secondn function is a bit trickier, but boils down to `Take an expression and OR it with another expression`. The tricky part is invoking the lambda (I usually unwrap it instead - it's easier to deal with in the queryable; but this is somewhat cleaner). There are easier ways to build the composite expression, but this one is the easiest to compose (you just `Or` together the individual expressions).

Comment: exactly the same is [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) with explanation

Comment: @Luaan I kind of understand, but my concept on this is lose at best. You say that is cleaner, ok, but could you make it dirtier/simpler?

Comment: @Luaan page just refreshed, I will look at that link

Comment: @AnswerIsNot42 Well, this *is* the simpler version. The dirty one is actually more complicated :) The only thing it simplifies is the resulting expression tree.

Comment: @Luaan ...haha dang :{

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to post this and take on the risk of being downvoted. But, in case I haven't missed the point, you can use an `||` (or) condition in your `where`:

```
query.Where(o => (o.Day == 12 && o.Month ==14 && o.Year == 1962) ||
                 (o.Day == 3 && o.Month == 4 && o.Year == 1977));
```

NOTE: This doesn't cater for all of the scenarios you've listed. Simply append more conditions on and be careful to use parenthesis to separate them correctly.

Comment: No, then #1 does not work... it is only once instance not 2. There is no or "||"

Comment: But it can only ever be one instance anyway? If `o.Day == 12` then it would be impossible for `o.Day == 3`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not load the dates into, say `HashSet<DateTime>`?

```
   HashSet<DateTime> birthDays = new HashSet<DateTime>() {
     new DateTime(1962, 1, 12), 
     new DateTime(1977, 4, 3), 
     ...
   };

   ...

   var result = query
    .Where(o => birtDays.Contains(o));
```

Or I've missed something?

Comment: I like this, it's neat - and saves you bloating the `where` as I've suggested. +1.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but CREATIVE!!! I liked it, but honestly I didn't even thinkn in that fashion to say no to this logic. Still a cool concept I'll log into ye-old brain. ....consider if I only needed IDs, so it would be ID, DAY, MONTH, YEAR. ...but still nice perspective